# How to use "hier", "dort" and "da" properly in German?

Tags: word-usage, adverb

In English "here" and "there" are typical pairs to indicate space and distance. The same is true of Hungarian ("itt" and "ott").

But in German it's a bit different: I have seen "da" many times in contexts when I would have used "hier". And I have even read "da" and "dort" together as a pair.

My question is: how to use these three deixes (spatial adverbs) properly in German?

Comment: Similar distinctions: _dies+ / jen+_, _hin / her_

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Generally, if 'hier', 'da' and 'dort' are used to designate place of varying distance, then
 - 'hier' refers to closest proximity
 - 'da' refers to a larger distance from the speaker
 - 'dort' indicates largest distance.

Imagine you talk to someone within an interesting park full of interesting features.

> 'Hier stand die alte Mauer der Stadt, da war der Wachturm, und dort (drüben) war das alte Rathaus'

However, nobody takes it as strict. In particular, 'da' and 'dort' are often used interchangably. These rules do not cover idiomatic usage (e.g. phrases like 'hier und da'), or you may completely dismiss the distance rules if you refer to a couple of locations and don't want to repeat the same word over and over again.

> (When revering to a map:) 'Hier ist die Autobahn A3, dort sind wir, und da war ist die Raststätte wo wir gestern gegessen haben'.

For more information about the (lack of) difference between 'da' and 'dort' see this article published from the [Philologisch-Historische Fakultät Universität Augsburg](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f07b-c_f07g/).

Comment: Laut Duden dürfen beide anscheinend auch im selben Kontext verwendet werden … Hast du nähere Informationen, warum das eine für weite, das andere für sehr weite Entfernung benutzt wird?

Comment: Es scheint ein debattierbares Thema zu sein: http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f07b-c_f07g/ - In formaler Sprache würde ich im Zweifelsfall das dreistufige Konzept verwenden. Das dürfte aber nur interessierten auffallen. Dem Rest ist es faktisch egal.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu Ich würde sagen, dass "Im Wald, da sind die Räuber" und "Auf der Alm, da gibt's koa Sünd" mit *dort* nicht stimmig klingen, kann aber am "idiomatischen" Charakter liegen.

Answer (score 10):

#### Rules of thumb

When forming German sentences as a native English speaker:

- Use *hier* for *here* and *da* for *there*.
- When targeting a high register, sometimes *dort* is better than *da* when it is emphasised.
- When there is any kind of doubt whether to use *da* or one of *hier, dort*, always prefer *da*.

When making sense of German utterings as a native English speaker:

- *Dort* translates to *[over] there*.
- *Hier* typically translates to *here*, but keep in mind that sometimes it translates to *there*.
- *Da* is more likely to translate to *there* than to *here*, but you should be equally open to both interpretations.
- If there is an opposition *hier - dort* or *hier - da*, it translates to *here - there*. (The same is true for an opposition *da - dort*. But that's rare because it's colloquial but most German speakers don't use *dort* in colloquial speech.)
- If something looks like a ternary opposition *hier - da - dort*, it's more likely that a binary opposition *hier - da/dort* is intended.

#### Rationale

Coming from English, the following should help to understand what's going on:

- *hier = here*
- *da/dort = there*
- Most German speakers don't make the *here-there / this-that* distinctions as systematically as most English speakers do. In the absence of a direct opposition as in "Do you mean this or that?", *hier* and *da* are basically interchangeable. This is a natural development because the *here - there* distinction can be used not just for space but also to refer to different previously mentioned parts of speech, similar to *the latter - the former*. Since the two aspects can result in contradictory distinctions, this starts a natural erosion process that seems to have progressed faster in German than in English.
- But *dort* belongs to a high register and is not affected by this erosion.
- *Hier* and especially *dort* automatically carries a certain amount of emphasis. Many speakers never use *dort* in natural speech (it may sound affected), and even *hier* is very often replaced by *da*.

#### Caveats

The above are just general guidelines. There are some pragmatic complications. E.g. the difference between the two uses of English *here and there* in the following examples can be rendered by different choices in German:

- There are a few problems here and there. - Es gibt hier und da noch ein paar Probleme. [*here and there* as a single idiom]
- The difference between here and there is striking. - Der Unterschied zwischen hier und dort ist beachtlich. [*here, and, there* as three individually interpreted words]

*Hier und dort* would be less standard and therefore slightly misleading in the first example; this is probably why *hier und dort* is preferred in the second example, though *hier und da* is acceptable as well. (As always, there may also be additional complications due to special regional preferences.)

Comment: As a speaker from Austria (so what I say may or may not apply to Southern Germany as well but is definitely wrong for the North), when speaking informally, I will use and interpret "da" as equivalent to "hier", never as equivalent to "dort". As for the final two example sentences,  I would be perfectly happy with "Es gibt hier und dort noch Probleme" or even "da und dort"; on the other hand, "Der Unterschied zwischen hier und da" would only leave me confused.

Comment: @wolfgang: OK, I think I overstated things that are actually just tendencies rather than strict rules. I'll try to fix this.

Comment: I don't think there *can* be an answer that covers 100% of German speakers and still covers everyday/colloquial speech. The stilted, high register is standardized, the rest just isn't. My comment should be enough to remind people that what you're saying about informal speech applies to a majority, but not to everyone, especially not in the south.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the previous answer, which takes care of the distinction of the three words with respect to each other, I though I'd add some detail to "da" being used synonymously with "here".

> I have seen "da" many times in contexts when I would have used "hier"

That's an absolutely correct observation.

Basically, "da" in colloquial speech, when referring to a place, can mean here, there, or a more general *"everywhere"* (as in, *"er ist wieder da"* for *"he's back; he has returned; he has come back"*).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In German, "hier" and "dort" are polar opposites, that correspond roughly to here and there.

But German uses an intermediate word for distance, "da," which means roughly "in this general area." So its meaning is context-dependent.

Most often, it means "here," that is hier ("near-here") and da ("far-here") are used in contrast to dort, or there.

But if the context is that "hier" is immediately around you, "da," which is a larger distance away, means "there." That is, in the sense of "near-there," as opposed to dort, which means "far-there."

Answer (score 0):

What about the merely temporal aspect of ‘da’  as in the poem by B. Brecht published in  1914:

*Moderne Legende*

„Als der Abend übers Schlachtfeld wehte
waren die Feinde geschlagen.
Klingend die Telegrafendrähte
haben die Kunde hinausgetragen.

Da schwoll am einen Ende der Welt… „