# Which word to use for "there", "dort" or "da"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, learning

I have been studying German lately. I have come across one course material. In that they are using *dort* and *da* interchangeably in different sentences. I want to know when you use what?

Comment: Hi Mankodaiyan, and welcome to german.SE. I voted to close your question, because it is already covered https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-use-hier-dort-and-da-properly-in-german Please tell us what specifically you want to know that is not covered in that question.

Comment: Thanks it is covered in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try looking at [each](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/usage-of-dort-or-da-in-proper-context) of the [several](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-use-hier-dort-and-da-properly-in-german) [posts](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/usage-of-dort-or-da-in-proper-context/5619#5619) that have asked [similar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/how-do-i-use-the-word-da/6033#6033) questions.  They give good explanations of the different contexts in which *da* and *dort* are appropriate. Note that ***da*** in some contexts also corresponds to situations in which an English speaker might say *here*.