# »da« vs. »hier« in Pronominaladverbien

Tags: difference, preposition, adverb, pronominal-adverb

Was ist der Unterschied, wenn man ein Pronominaladverb mit »da« oder »hier« bildet?
z.B.:

> - *dafür* vs. *hierfür* (*wofür?*)
> - *damit* vs. *hiermit* (*womit?*)
> - *dabei* vs. *hierbei* (*wobei?*)
> - ...

Ich habe bloß bemerkt, dass »hier« nicht mit allen Präpositionen benutzt werden kann. Ein Muttersprachler hat mir bestätigt, dass es einen Unterschied gibt, er konnte ihn mir aber nicht erklären, oder die Regel formulieren.

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-use-hier-dort-and-da-properly-in-german (englisch)

Comment: @Deni, what are you missing in my answer?

Comment: _da-_ is the caseless compound stem of the determiner _der/das/die_ (article or pronoun). In _Pronominaladverbien_ it basically replaces the pronoun juxtaposed with the preposition, e.g. _damit_ ↔ _mit dem/der/den(en)_ vs. _ohne den/das/die_. _hier-_ ist mostly reserved to deictic use, i.e. the speaker/writer can point to the reference.

Comment: Was meinst du mit "Unterschied"? semantisch? grammatikalisch?

Comment: Mehre gute Bespiele sind gewünscht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich würde sagen, der Unterschied von "da" und "hier" in Pronominaladverb ist derselbe, wie bei "da" und "hier" im Allgemeinen. "Da" bezieht sich auf etwas, was weiter weg liegt oder auf etwas, auf das man zeigen kann. Es drückt eine gewisse Distanz aus, ob räumlich, zeitlich oder mental. Und "hier" auf etwas, dass sich in unmittelbarer Nähe befindet. Um auf das Beispiel von Iris einzugehen:

> Was möchten Sie hierfür?

... fragt man korrekterweise für etwas, was man in der Hand hält (oder so nah ist, dass man noch nicht einmal zeigen braucht), wohingegen:

> Was möchten Sie dafür?

... sich eher auf etwas bezieht, worauf man zeigt (z.B. Ware in einem Schaukasten).

Weitere Beispiel:

> Worum dreht es sich hierbei?

... meint eine Sache, die gerade relevant ist bzw. von der gerade gesprochen wird, allerdings:

> Worum dreht es sich dabei?

... meint eher etwas, worüber z.B. andere sprechen oder eine Sache, die im Fernsehen zu sehen ist, etc.

> Was soll ich hiermit?

... könnte sich wieder auf einen Gegenstand beziehen, den man in der Hand hat oder der sich nah am Körper befindet.

> Was soll ich damit?

.. könnte sich eher auf etwas beziehen, auf das man zeigt.

> Sie ist nicht hierzu bereit.

"Hierzu" meint eine Sache, die gerade geschied und in die alle Angesprochenen involviert sind, wohingegen

> Sie ist nicht dazu bereit.

... eher eine Sache meint, von der zuvor zwar gesprochen wurde, allerdings kann diese Sache in der Zukunft liegen und die Angesprochenen müssen nicht unbedingt involviert sein.

> Ich bin neugierig hierauf.

Eine Sache, die jetzt gleich passieren wird oder gerade begonnen hat (zeitliche Nähe).

> Ich bin neugierig darauf.

Kann auch eine Sache meinen, die in der Zukunft liegt.

> Hiernach gibt es Kaffee und Kuchen.

Nach der Sitzung/Besprechung/etc., die gerade stattfindet.

> Danach gibt es Kaffee und Kuchen.

Nach der Sitzung/etc., von der man gerade gesprochen hat, die aber in der Zukunft liegen kann.

**Zusammenfassung:**

"hier" - Nähe;
"da" - Distanz

- Bezug auf Gegenstand o.ä.: räumliche Nähe/Distanz
- Bezug auf Ereignis o.ä.: zeitliche Nähe/Distanz
- Bezug auf Angelegenheit o.ä.: mentale/persönliche Nähe/Distanz

Wenn allerdings kein solcher Bezug hergestellt werden kann, sind die besagten Wörter als Synonyme anzusehen. Beispiel:

> Wir backen einen Kuchen. Hierzu/Dazu nehmen wir vier Eier, ... (Anweisung in einem Rezept z.B.)

In diesem Beispiel gibt es keinen räumlichen/zeitlichen/etc. Bezug, es wird sich nur auf den Kuchen bezogen, den es (allgemein) zu backen gilt. Daher gibt es hier keinen Unterschied zwischen "hierzu" und "dazu".

Comment: deine Antwort gefällt mir am besten, könntest du sie bitte mit noch ein paar Bespielen. Z.B.: hiermit/damit, hierzu/dazu, hierauf/darauf, hier*/da*.

Comment: Gern. Ich hoffe, es hilft. Vielleicht sollte ich noch anmerken, dass oft diese Wörter als Synonyme behandelt werden. Denn im Duden steht z.B. als Synonym zu "hierzu" "dazu". Wie stark der Unterschied tatsächlich ist, kommt wohl auf den Kontext an.

Comment: dein Beispiel mit dem Ein hat mich ein bisschen verwirrt, weil mein deutsche Kollege, sage mir, dass der folgende Satz nicht korrekt it: "Ich kann nicht essen. Hierfür brauche ich einen Löffel" Mit "dafür" ist der aber korrekt. Könntest du auch das "involviert" zu der Zusammenfassung hinzufügen?

Comment: Ich bin der Meinung, dass dieser Satz sehrwohl korrekt ist. Siehe http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hierfuer. Eine hier genannte Bedeutung für "hierfür" ist: "für den soeben genannten Zweck". In deinem Satz ist der soeben genannte Zweck zu essen.

Answer (score 5):

> da...

referes to something general,

> hier...

refers more specific to something you just mentioned or that is close to you.

I think, you can always replace "hier..." with "da..." (at least I can't think of any exception).

**For example:**

In a shop, when you show on something, you would ask:

> Was möchten Sie **hierfür/dafür**? *How much (money) do you want for that?*

But if you talk about something that is not near you:

> Mein Mann hat einen neuen Computer gekauft und **dafür** so viel Geld ausgegeben. *My husband bought a new computer and he spend so much money on it.*

Answer (score 2):

Pronominaladverbien mit "da" bzw. "hier" können in der Regel mit allen Präpositionen verbunden werden, die

- mit Dativ oder Akkusativ gebildet werden
- in Beziehung zu konkreten oder abstrakten Gegenständen gesetzt werden können.

> Ich spreche **über das Buch**.
>
> Ich spreche **darüber**.

Ausnahme aber z.B. "**ohne**".

Ist die Verbindung erlaubt, dann m.W. in jedem Fall sowohl mit "da" als auch mit "hier".
Die Adverbien sind grammatikalisch quasi austauschbar.

z.B. da-/hierzwischen, da-/hiergegen

Natürlich entstehen nicht unerhebliche semantische Unterschiede, weil "da" hinweisende, "hier" jedoch herweisende (vereinfacht gesagt, auf den Ort der Äußerungsperson verweisende) Funktion hat. S. hierzu auch Iris' Antwort.